# Use pipe method for multiple operations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have below code

```
import pandas as pd
dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C'], 'col2' : ['Z', 'Z', 'X', 'Y']})
Use_pipe = dat1.pipe(lambda x : x or x.to_csv('aa.csv'))
```

The last line fails. Is there any way to make it work i.e. simultaneously passing values to `Use_pipe` and save the dataframe using `pipe`?

Comment: your code is unclear - either print the dataframe or write to csv?

Comment: both, using same line with `pipe` method

Comment: you have an or statment

Comment: `dat1.to_csv('aa.csv').pipe('whatever function')`

Comment: @sammywemmy your suggestion fails with error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pipe'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is with pyjanitor's [also](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.also.also) function:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd
dat1.also(lambda df: df.to_csv('aa.csv')).pipe('whatever function')
```

You can also just define a function and use that in your pipe:

```py
def return_df(df, func, *args, **kwargs):
    func(df.copy(), *args, **kwargs)
    return df

dat1.return_df(lambda df: df.to_csv('aa.csv')).pipe(wateva)
```

Another way would be to use a tuple, coupled with an index (hacky):

```py
dat1.pipe(lambda df: (df, df.to_csv('aaa.csv'))[0]).pipe(wateva)
```

Comment: Thanks. I liked the last approach. This is innovative.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code you should invert the conditions:

```
Use_pipe = dat1.pipe(lambda x : not x.to_csv('aa.csv') or x)
```

Another trick could be to use a ternary:

```
import pandas as pd

dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C'],
                     'col2' : ['Z', 'Z', 'X', 'Y']})

Use_pipe = dat1.pipe(lambda x : x if x.to_csv('aa.csv') else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a named function it's possible:

```
def f(x):
    x.to_csv('aa.csv')
    return x
    
Use_pipe = dat1.pipe(f)
```

Output:

```
>>> Use_pipe
  col1 col2
0    A    Z
1    B    Z
2    A    X
3    C    Y
```